# Use table row coloring for cells in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/) offers classes to [color table rows](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/) like so:

```
<tr class="success">
```

I like the color choice and the class naming. Now what I would like to do, is to re-use these classes and apply them on table cells, too. Obviously, I could define my own classes with the same colors and be done with it.

But is there a shorthand in CSS. LESS, to let the `td` inherit the classes?

Comment: You'd like per-cell coloring?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can override the default css rules with this:

```
.table tbody tr > td.success {
  background-color: #dff0d8 !important;
}

.table tbody tr > td.error {
  background-color: #f2dede !important;
}

.table tbody tr > td.warning {
  background-color: #fcf8e3 !important;
}

.table tbody tr > td.info {
  background-color: #d9edf7 !important;
}

.table-hover tbody tr:hover > td.success {
  background-color: #d0e9c6 !important;
}

.table-hover tbody tr:hover > td.error {
  background-color: #ebcccc !important;
}

.table-hover tbody tr:hover > td.warning {
  background-color: #faf2cc !important;
}

.table-hover tbody tr:hover > td.info {
  background-color: #c4e3f3 !important;
}
```

`!important` is needed as bootstrap actually colours the cells individually (afaik it's not possible to just apply background-color to a tr). I couldn't find any colour variables in my version of bootstrap but that's the basic idea anyway.

Comment: It seems to be integrated into bootstrap by now (version 3.3.4) (.table-hover>tbody>tr.danger:hover>td, .table-hover>tbody>tr.danger:hover>th, .table-hover>tbody>tr:hover>.danger, .table-hover>tbody>tr>td.danger:hover, .table-hover>tbody>tr>th.danger:hover {
    background-color: #ebcccc;)

Answer (score 3):

Bottom line is that you'll have to write a new css rule for that.

Depending on which bundle of Twitter Bootstrap you're using, you should have variables for the various colours.

Try something like:

```
.table tbody tr > td {
  &.success { background-color: $green; }
  &.info { background-color: $blue; }
  ...
}
```

Surely there's a way to use `extend` or the LESS equivalent to avoid repeating the same styling.

Answer (score 3):

With the current version of Bootstrap (3.3.7), it is possible to color a single cell of a table like so:

`<td class = 'text-center col-md-4 success'>`

Answer (score 2):

Updated html for the newer bootstrap

```
    .table-hover > tbody > tr.danger:hover > td {
     background-color: red !important;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr.warning:hover > td {
     background-color: yellow !important;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr.success:hover > td {
     background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With less you can set it up like this;

```
.table tbody tr {
    &.error > td { background-color: red !important; }
    &.error:hover > td { background-color: yellow !important; }
    &.success > td { background-color: green !important; }
    &.success:hover > td { background-color: yellow !important; }
    ...
}
```

That did the trick for me.